# How to make an input restriction function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I want to do is put a character and length restriction in an input using this rules:

> A combination of at least ten numbers,  letters and punctuation marks
>   (like ! and &)

and if the user didnt complete the rules the input value will be back to empty again.

My problem is I'm still a beginner and my current code wont work as i wanted. Can anyone help me with this please.

Current output:  http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/271/

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').on('blur', function () {
        $('#example').change(inputVerify);
        inputVerify()
    })
    $('#example').on('keydown', function () {
        $('#example').change(inputVerify);
        inputVerify()
    })
    $('#example').change(inputVerify);

    function inputVerify(value) {
        return /^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,20}$/.test(value) && /[a-z]/.test(value) && /\d/.test(value)

    };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to tell you "how to do it better in general", but what about giving live feedback instead of reverting a bad entry? This way the user can a) see as soon as it is correct, b) correct his former entry:

```
$("#example").on('keydown',function(){
    if(!inputVerify($("#example").val())){
        $("#example").css("border","1px solid red");
    } else {
        $("#example").css("border","1px solid black");
    }

});

function inputVerify(value){
return /^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,20}$/.test(value)
        && /[a-z]/.test(value) 
        && /\d/.test(value) 

};
```

Comment: +1 If I have just typed in a password which is "A combination of at least ten numbers, letters and punctuation marks (like ! and &)", and made a typo (didn't press Shift hard enough, so I had 1 instead of !, for example), I don't want to retype the whole damn thing. It's even worse as it is a password - those are usually hidden by asterisks so I may not even know I had a 1 instead of ! - all I'd see is my password disappearing mysteriously. Was it wrong? Was it correct and "hiding" it is the correct behaviour? I wouldn't know at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You should really do this only on blur, it should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').on('blur', function(){
        if( !inputVerify() ) {
             $(this).val('');   
        }
    });
});    

function inputVerify(value){
    return /^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,20}$/.test(value)
        && /[a-z]/.test(value) 
        && /\d/.test(value) 
};
```

You see, your inputVerify function returns `true` or `false` and you would have to remove the input yourself by `$(this).val('');`.

The jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/272/

Please note that I have not tested your regex, as I am not too familiar with them, yours seem to work though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, note I did not check your regular expression:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').keydown(inputVerify);

    function inputVerify(event) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (!(/^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,20}$/.test(value) 
            && /[a-z]/.test(value) 
            && /\d/.test(value))) {
                $(this).val('');
        }
    };
});
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/274/)

The function inputVerify catches the event passed by the keydown handler and uses the `$(this)` which refers to the element the event is triggered on to get the value of the input.

And then, if the regex tests fail, empty the input.